# Add a value to all cells in a column in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have found this macro on a website and it does exactly what I need it to do with the exception of I need to copy it down for all the rows in my spreadsheet and all sheets.  Can anyone help me with that?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    [B1] = [B1] + [A1]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ThisWorkbook`, put your code in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event to make it change when any worksheet is changed. For example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'put your code here
End Sub
```

So for your above code, it would be this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    [B1] = [B1] + [A1]
End Sub
```